# How to embed a PE file to another PE files

Tags: windows, metasploit, python, windows-10

So what I want to do basically is what [BDFproxy](https://github.com/secretsquirrel/BDFProxy) does on the go, I want to modify a file *(on the disk)* to embed another PE in it and have both working, it does not matter if they work concurrently or when the main program finishes the embedded program works I just want to embed them in any way possible and if the Metasploit framework `(peinjector post exploitation module)` and BDFproxy can do that it is not impossible

I tried to write a python script to try and do that however when I run the outputted file it says ***this app cannot run on your pc*** here is the script:

```
import pefile

def embed_pe(main_exe_path, embedded_exe_path):
    # Load the main executable
    main_pe = pefile.PE(main_exe_path)

    # Load the embedded executable
    embedded_pe = pefile.PE(embedded_exe_path)

    # Create a new section in the main executable for the embedded executable
    name = ".embedded"
    virtual_size = len(embedded_pe.__data__)
    raw_size = virtual_size
    characteristics = 0xE0000020 # READ | WRITE | EXECUTE | CODE

    # Calculate the virtual offset and raw offset
    number_of_section = main_pe.FILE_HEADER.NumberOfSections
    last_section = number_of_section - 1
    virtual_offset = main_pe.sections[last_section].VirtualAddress + main_pe.sections[last_section].Misc_VirtualSize
    raw_offset = main_pe.sections[last_section].PointerToRawData + main_pe.sections[last_section].SizeOfRawData

    # Create a new section header
    new_section_header = pefile.SectionStructure(main_pe.__IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER_format__, pe=main_pe)
    new_section_header.Name = name.encode()
    new_section_header.Misc_VirtualSize = virtual_size
    new_section_header.VirtualSize = virtual_size
    new_section_header.SizeOfRawData = raw_size
    new_section_header.PointerToRawData = raw_offset
    new_section_header.VirtualAddress = virtual_offset
    new_section_header.Characteristics = characteristics

    # Add the new section header to the list of sections
    main_pe.sections.append(new_section_header)

    # Modify the main headers
    main_pe.FILE_HEADER.NumberOfSections += 1
    main_pe.OPTIONAL_HEADER.SizeOfImage += raw_size
    main_pe.OPTIONAL_HEADER.AddressOfEntryPoint = virtual_offset

    # Embed the embedded executable into the new section
    main_pe.__data__ = main_pe.__data__[:raw_offset] + embedded_pe.__data__ + main_pe.__data__[raw_offset:]

    # Save the modified main executable
    print(main_exe_path)
    main_pe.write("modified_"+main_exe_path)

# Usage
embed_pe("cygwin.exe", "message.exe")
```

So what is the way to achieve my goal and if there is what am I doing wrong in my Python script